# How do I undo 6 local commits in GIT?

Tags: git

I am new to GIT. I tried committing code to my brach. The `commit` would work fine but `push` would fail because I was not adhering to the *standard* `push` comments (not the issue here) . Now, I have 6 failed commits. 
`git status` says : *Your branch is ahead of 'branchX' by 6 commits.*
How can I undo all my failed commits?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Revert to a previous Git commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/revert-to-a-previous-git-commit)

Answer (score 2):

git reset command should deal with it.
It will undo the last 6 commits from the head.
Note that you will lose your current changes in this local repository (if any)

```
$ git reset --hard HEAD~6
```

Comment: If you commited 6 times, not pushed and want to trash it away, this is a good way.

Comment: @LeFlou - Ok.. I could try that.. There are no differences between the 6 commits

Comment: @TheLostMind, What do you mean ?

Comment: @LeFlou - I meant to say that I don't need the files that I changed in the last 6 commits

Comment: @TheLostMind, Take a look at [git reset documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset)

Answer (score 1):

Most probably, `git reset --hard <to-what-point>`, but please create a local branch first on your HEAD, or you will have a hard time finding your commits afterwards. Once you are sure they are not needed any more, just delete the branch.

Also, please note that if your problem is just in bad commit messages, then `git rebase --interactive` will let you easily rewrite the commits and correct messages.

Comment: @TheLostMind: and have you used "reword" option during interactive rebase? see https://robots.thoughtbot.com/git-interactive-rebase-squash-amend-rewriting-history

Comment: Nope.. Will go through the article.. Thanks.